# Scaling multiple sub-drawings to be the same size within an SVG drawing

Tags: svg

I'd like to create a grid of drawings that were created by different authors in varying programs and have each drawing scale down to the same size. Note that all drawings will be created in the same aspect ratio.

Here's an example. I've tried setting a viewBox wrapper around each drawing with preserveAspectRatio to get it to scale. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18in" height="12in" viewBox="0 0 1296 864">
 <defs>
  <svg width="3.25in" height="5.25in" viewBox="0 0 234 378" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
   <svg id="ad">
    <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-37.5,-37.5)"> <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,20,10)"> <ellipse cx="143.406" cy="150.564" rx="107.776" ry="107.172" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1px;"/> </g> <path d="M842.64,75L968.522,145.424L920.439,259.373L764.841,259.373L716.758,145.424L842.64,75Z" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1px;"/> <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,20,-20)"> <rect x="35.629" y="1385.57" width="240.5" height="222.221" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1px;"/> </g> <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,25.1242,54.6384)"> <path d="M953.901,1534.08C967.723,1515.42 975,1494.26 975,1472.72C975,1404.99 904.434,1350 817.516,1350C730.598,1350 660.032,1404.99 660.032,1472.72C660.032,1494.26 667.308,1515.42 681.131,1534.08L953.901,1534.08Z" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1px;"/> </g> <path d="M571.57,566.256L620.774,717.688L779.999,717.688L651.183,811.278L700.386,962.71L571.57,869.12L442.755,962.71L491.958,811.278L363.142,717.688L522.367,717.688L571.57,566.256Z" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1px;"/> </g>
   </svg>
  </svg>
  <svg width="3.25in" height="5.25in" viewBox="0 0 234 378" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
   <svg id="il">
    <rect class="cls-1" x="2.6" y="4.45" width="42.14" height="42.14"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="171.37 243.59 95.5 265.83 38.29 211.25 56.96 134.41 132.84 112.17 190.04 166.75 171.37 243.59"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="216.79" cy="17.66" r="13.21"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="216.79" cy="363.73" r="11.68"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="21.7" cy="356.31" r="19.1"/>
   </svg>
  </svg>
 </defs>
 <svg x="0"><use href="#il" /></svg> 
 <svg x="234"><use href="#ad" /></svg> 
</svg>
```

Comment: the `<use>` element can take a `width` and a `height` attributes. Use the `width` and the `height` to set the size you need. Use the `x` and `y` attributes to position the `<use>` element. You don't need to wrap the use in an svg element

Comment: If I set a width and height on the `use` element then it just crops the image, it doesn't scale it.

Comment: And you will need a viewBox for the #ad and #il svg elements

Comment: Have you added a width height x and y attributes to the use elements? Can you edit your question and replace the code with what you have right now?

Comment: I have figured it out from what you told me. I'll answer my own question below. Can I offer you some money via PayPal for your assistance?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, with the help of @enxaneta I figured out how to make this work. Here is the resulting file:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="18in" height="12in" viewBox="0 0 1296 864">
  <defs>
                <svg id="ad" viewBox="0 0 975 1575" spreserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
                        <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,-37.5,-37.5)"> <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,20,10)"> <ellipse cx="143.406" cy="150.564" rx="107.776" ry="107.172" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1px;"/> </g> <path d="M842.64,75L968.522,145.424L920.439,259.373L764.841,259.373L716.758,145.424L842.64,75Z" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1px;"/> <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,20,-20)"> <rect x="35.629" y="1385.57" width="240.5" height="222.221" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1px;"/> </g> <g transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,25.1242,54.6384)"> <path d="M953.901,1534.08C967.723,1515.42 975,1494.26 975,1472.72C975,1404.99 904.434,1350 817.516,1350C730.598,1350 660.032,1404.99 660.032,1472.72C660.032,1494.26 667.308,1515.42 681.131,1534.08L953.901,1534.08Z" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1px;"/> </g> <path d="M571.57,566.256L620.774,717.688L779.999,717.688L651.183,811.278L700.386,962.71L571.57,869.12L442.755,962.71L491.958,811.278L363.142,717.688L522.367,717.688L571.57,566.256Z" style="fill:none;stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:1px;"/> </g>
                </svg>
                <svg id="il" viewBox="0 0 234 378" spreserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
                        <rect class="cls-1" x="2.6" y="4.45" width="42.14" height="42.14"/><polygon class="cls-1" points="171.37 243.59 95.5 265.83 38.29 211.25 56.96 134.41 132.84 112.17 190.04 166.75 171.37 243.59"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="216.79" cy="17.66" r="13.21"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="216.79" cy="363.73" r="11.68"/><circle class="cls-1" cx="21.7" cy="356.31" r="19.1"/>
                </svg>
                
  </defs>
  <use href="#il" width="3.25in" height="5.25in" />
  <use href="#ad" x="3.25in" width="3.25in" height="5.25in" />
</svg>
```

You have to copy the viewBox from the original drawing into the svg element that wraps it, then you can specify width and height in the use element.